# How to feed custom data into highmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, highmaps

I am successfully displaying the US Counties map using highmaps, including customization of options, etc. Because I'm such a jQuery newby, I can't figure out how to replace the highcharts data URL with a custom URL that I'm creating to return the code, name, and value for each count that I want to highlight. Below is the pertinent code that gets the sample data, which is displaying fine:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-counties-unemployment.json&callback=?', function (data) {

            var countiesMap = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all-all']);
            var lines = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all-all'], 'mapline');

            // add state acronym for tooltip
            Highcharts.each(countiesMap, function (mapPoint) {
                var state = mapPoint.properties["hc-key"].substring(3, 5);
                mapPoint.name = mapPoint.name + ', ' + state.toUpperCase();
            });

            var options = {
                ...
```

I have tried to use a little hard-coded array to start with (and eventually replace that with the real-time data that my custom URL will provide), but that currently breaks the whole page. Here is my code for that (with data for just two counties):

```
var data = [{"code":"us-al-001","name":"Autauga County, AL","value":1},
{"code":"us-il-019","name":"Champaign County, IL",value:3}];
```

Any thoughts on how to bootstrap this with the right syntax to 1) start with a hard-coded array of the counties I want to highlight, and then 2) move up to a custom URL that I'm working on which will return JSON that will fill the data array would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your last "value" string is not in quotation marks as the previous one "value", that can break everything.

Comment: Please setup JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks JV Lobo - the missing quote marks were the problem!